# Why doesn't Windows network utilise the hardware's capabilities?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have Windows home network setup which I use to stream media between devices, transfer files, etc. My networking gear is all up-to-date and I have 802.11n on all devices, the wireless link speed is never below 150 mbps and everything works. But still the network works painfully slow, I can rarely get speeds above 1 megabyte per sec. I know that 150 mbps means only 18 megabytes, but I'd be thrilled if I can get even 5. What can be the cause of this pain? Is there any way around it?

**DETAILS:** The router is an Edimax br-6228nc V2. It operates on 2.4 Ghz and the antenna is 9 dbi. On one PC I have D-link DWA 132 adapter and other two have Ralink 300 mbps wireless cards. There is Windows 7 on all PCs and they are all core i3, 4 GB RAM,etc

Comment: The problem is your networking gear not Windows.  Your description of the problem is hard to follow.  This limit transfer speeds from other devices from within the network or outside of the network?

Comment: If you cannot exceed 1 Megabyte per second transfers speeds within your network that indicates an entirely different problem than if you cannot exceed those transfers speeds on traffic coming into your network.

Comment: @G-man We can't help you calculate what your network bandwidth should be, or help you figure out what's wrong, unless you give us technical details of your equipment and environment, including the exact make & model of your AP and your client WNIC. We also need to know your typical PHY rate (not the max speed the link is capable of, but what signaling rate it actually tends to use) and RSSI. It would also be best to test your performance with a reliable TCP performance tester such as iperf 2.0.x. And please don't mix units. Put everything in 1,000,000's of bits per second (megabits).

Comment: 150Mbps translates to more like 6MB/s. You're probably forgetting to take into account three things: First, all data has to be sent twice, once from the source to the access point and once from the access point to the destination. Second, the sender has to negotiate for access to the channel, it can't just transmit whenever it feels like it. Third, for single stream 802.11n devices, it takes time for to "turn the link around" -- you can't instantaneously go from transmitting at power to receiving with full sensitivity without missing a beat.

Comment: @Ramhound okay I understand what you're saying now, and I *am* talking about within-network transfers.

Comment: So what is your actual measured mbps?  150 mbps is just your theoretical maximum on 802.11n hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound How do I get the actual mbps? The maximum is 300 mbps for the router and the wifi cards, and in task manager the link speed fluctuates between 120-200

Comment: I can guarantee you will NEVER get 300 mbps on 802.11n hardware.  66% efficiency is actually pretty good.  I would need to know more about the device that is connecting, the router, what frequency was being used, and have you fix all your measurements into a single unit before I could help.

Comment: @Ramhound I added  some details. Sorry for pinging you continuously

Comment: Based on the information you provided you are already at the maximum speeds you will get with the hardware you have.  The maximum for the [router](http://www.edimaxstore.com/Edimax-BR-6228nC-V2) is only 150 mbps.  *If you want faster speeds upgrade your equipment.*  While each client has the capability to transfer at faster speeds then the router your router does not.  The more devices you have connected means the less bandwidth each device will have.  *You have bottom of the barrel hardware basically.*

Answer (score 1):

Your Edimax BR-6228nC V2 is only capable of 150 megabit/sec operation in 2.4GHz, and only when using 40MHz-wide channels, WMM on, and either no security or WPA2 AES-CCMP security enabled. And only when on a clean (interference-free; unlikely in 2.4GHz because of neighbors' networks and Bluetooth and microwave ovens and 2.4GHz cordless phones and baby monitors and Wii remotes and wireless web/security cams, etc. etc.) 40MHz-wide channel with a similarly-capable client in optimal range (not too close, but especially not too far).

But let's say you've got all that. A good rule of thumb for 802.11n is that your TCP/IP throughput will be about 60-80% of your 802.11 PHY rate (the per-packet signaling rate). So let's take the the ideal case and say you have really high-quality hardware that does frame aggregation optimally and can achieve 80% efficiency.

150 * 0.8 = 120 megabit/sec or about 14.3 MebiBytes/sec.

But you're talking about transfers from one wireless device to another within your home. Even assuming that everything is ideal as per above, and that the second client is also within optimal range, your bandwidth expectation have to be cut in half, because every transmission goes across the channel twice. Once from the source to the AP, and then again from the AP to the destination.

120 / 2 = 60 megabits/sec or about 7.1 MebiBytes/sec.

Again, that's your perfect-world ideal best case. In reality, you'll never find a perfectly clean 40MHz-wide swath of the 2.4GHz band, and your clients aren't likely to always be within the range where they can keep the PHY rate pegged to 150 megabits/sec, and you're probably copying files over a relatively inefficient protocol like SMB.

It's not hard to imagine those real-world factors knocking you down to 1 MebiBytes/sec.

The weakest link in the chain is your 150 megabit/sec router. Even upgrading to a 2 spatial stream 300 megabit/sec device may double your throughput.

But even that is just 2007-era Wi-Fi speeds. To really get up to date, you'd need 3 spatial stream 802.11ac gear (1300 megabit/sec PHY rate). With that kind of gear, even in real-world conditions and wireless-to-wireless, you could see 20 MebiBytes/sec transfers.

Comment: Perfect response :-)